# argis api for js remove sun shadow

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I use **arcgis 4.9 api for javascript** to develop my application. I don't know how to remove the shadow in my earth. I try to set **directShadowsEnabled** to false or true, but it doesn't work. I have understood **directShadowsEnabled** couldn't switch the shadow of sun. So can you help me? Thanks for your patience.

here is my code:)

```
var map = new Map({
 logo: false,
 basemap: "satellite",
 ground: "world-elevation"
});

var view = new SceneView({
 alphaCompositingEnabled: true,
 container: props.container,
 map: map,
 environment: {
  lighting: {
  directShadowsEnabled: false,
  ambientOcclusionEnabled: false,
  cameraTrackingEnabled: false
  },
 background: {
  type: "color",
  color: [0, 0, 0, 0]
 },
 starsEnabled: false,
 }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  To get the best answer, you should show include the part of the code where you think the problem lies. Otherwise its too hard to reply correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I will add the part of my code soon after.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html#environment

> directShadowsEnabled Boolean optional Default Value:false
>
> Indicates whether to show shadows cast by the sun. Shadows are only
>   displayed for real world 3D objects. Terrain doesn't cast shadows. In
>   local scenes at small zoom levels, shadows are not displayed.

Setting the `environment.lighting.directShadowsEnabled` to `false` should disable the shadows for 3D objects.

If you see the shadows for 3D objects even with the `directShadowsEnabled` set to `false`, you should have an error somewhere and post all your code in your question